# bash shell - ssh remote script capture output and exit code?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote

I wish to use shell to invoke a script on a remote server.
I would like to capture the output of that script (its logging messages) and the exit code it returns.

If I do this:

```
ssh user@server /usr/local/scripts/test_ping.sh
echo "$?"
```

I get the exit code but can't capture the remote logging messages .

If I do this:

```
local RESULTS=$(ssh user@server /usr/local/scripts/test_ping.sh)
echo "$?" 
LOG "${RESULTS}";
```

I get to log my output using my LOG function but can't seem to get a correct exit code, I assume the code I get is the code from the varianble assignment.

I would like to continue to use my LOG function to capture all output as it formats and sends things to a file, syslog, and the screen for me.

How can I capture results in a var AND get the correct exit code from the remote script?

Comment: output only: http://superuser.com/questions/130443/remotely-run-script-on-unix-get-output-locally | http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/redirect-stdout-over-ssh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143006/retrieving-the-result-of-a-bash-command-run-from-ssh-into-a-variable

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the correct error code is because `local` is actually the last thing executed. You need to declare the variable as local prior to running the command.

```
local RESULTS
RESULTS=$(ssh user@server /usr/local/scripts/test_ping.sh)
echo $?
```

You can see the issue here:

```
$ bar() { foo=$(ls asdkjasd 2>&1); echo $?; }; bar
2
$ bar() { local foo=$(ls asdkjasd 2>&1); echo $?; }; bar
0
$ bar() { local foo; foo=$(ls asdkjasd 2>&1); echo $?; }; bar
2
```

Answer (score 10):

The "local" seems to be the problem. This works for me:

```
local RESULTS
RESULTS=$(ssh user@server /usr/local/scripts/test_ping.sh)
echo $?
```

Comment: you were right too, but jodanm was more faster!

Comment: Yes, 26 seconds.

Comment: Not an English class but it's incorrect to say 'more faster'.

Comment: I know it was a joke. A bad one I suppose. On the internet nobody knows you are a dog.

Comment: also jordanm's answer explains WHY this was the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, neither of the answers above traps the ssh error code and message, which could be done as follows (ignore my custom vars & funcs):

```
# move the deployment package from the tmp dir
msg=$(ssh -i "$(eval echo $identity_file)" -o ConnectTimeout=5 "$ssh_user"'@'"$ssh_server" \
sudo -iu "$etl_user" bash "$tgt_deployment_dir"'/src/bash/'"$run_unit/$run_unit"'.sh' \
    -a create-relative-package 2>&1)

# fail on any non-success
export exit_code=$?
export err_msg="network error: ""$msg"
test $exit_code -ne 0 && echo "$err_msg" && exit $exit_code
```