# Returning a value from a script running on a slave machine

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have a script (on my local machine). In the script, a connection is established via ssh to a slave machine and it runs a build script on the slave:

```
ssh $user@$slave_ip bash $dest_root/$dest_dir/slave_run
```

Is there a way to capture the exit code that is returned from the slave_run script in a parent script variable?

Comment: possible duplicte [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code)

Comment: That's IMHO not a duplicate question, but shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command (with added double quotes):

```
ssh "$user@$slave_ip" bash "$dest_root/$dest_dir/slave_run"
```

The capture the exit code will be in `$?` after the execution of that command.

Example:

```
$ ssh someserver sh -c 'false'
$ echo $?
1
```

To capture it:

```
$ ssh someserver somecommand
$ code=$?
```

Alternatively, get the command on the server to output the exit code and capture it as a string:

```
$ code=$( ssh server sh -c "somecommand; echo \$?" )
```

In your case:

```
$ code=$( ssh "$user@$slave_ip" sh -c "$dest_root/$dest_dir/slave_run; echo \$?" )
```

It's necessary to escape the `$` of `$?` as the command is within double quotes and we'd like `$?` to be evaluated by the shell on the server side, not by the shell on the client.

Answer (score 0):

To examine the exit code, you need to examine a special variable which is "$?" This variable tell's you the exit code of the last command you ran.

```
ssh $user@$slave_ip 'bash $dest_root/$dest_dir/slave_run ; echo $?'
```

Comment: Thanks @Hunter.S.Thompson. Is the solution here: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code) a similar solution to what you wrote?

Comment: Yes except the question is for a script.

Comment: So if I were to save the exit code in a variable in the parent script, how can I assign it?

Comment: @RaphPeres `code=$( ssh ... )`

Comment: @Kusalananda so it would be `ERROR=$(ssh $user@$slave_ip 'bash $dest_root/$dest_dir/slave_run ; echo $?')`