# Display output of $() execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have the command below that I used to run without `$()`, but I have to in order to capture the return code of the remote script. The issue is that now I don't see the command output unless I `cat` it. Can I see the output during execution?

```
set -o pipefail
COMMAND=$(ssh ${RMT_HOST} ${RMT_DIR}/${SCRIPT_NAME} ${ARGUMENTS} < /dev/null |& tee -a ${RMT_EXEC_LOG})
RETCODE=$?
```

**EDIT**
Just to clear why I use `$()` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code) is a link

Comment: The usage of `$()` does not affect the return code...

Comment: Seconding that, you don't have to use command substitution to use `$?`.

Comment: `$?` is going to contain the return code of `tee`, not `ssh`. Use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

Comment: @jordanm this is way I use `set -o pipefail`

Comment: Your link doesn't explain why you use command substitution. If anything, the question itself makes it clear in the beginning that `$?` works fine without command substitution.

Comment: You right, I just checked it. It was a long day :)

Answer (score 1):

If the question you're *actually* asking is "how can I both capture and display the output of a process?", you're on the right track with `tee`, but as others have noted, if you later look at the exit code by inspecting `$?`, you will be getting the exit code of `tee` and not of the command run through it.

It's easy to store the output and look at it later, but you need to capture the exit code immediately.  Better, then, to use a temporary file and handle the output separately:

```
scratch="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -fr "$scratch"' EXIT
--SOME LONG COMMAND-- > "$scratch"
returncode=$?
--HANDLER FOR RETURNCODE--
cat "$scratch" >> /path/to/persistent_logfile
```