# bash script executed over ssh returns incorrect exit code 0

Tags: shell, ssh, exit-status

I am trying to automate a process which involves running scripts on various machines via ssh. It is vital to capture both output and the return code (for the detection of errors).

Setting the exit code explicitly works as expected:

```
~$ ssh host exit 5 && echo OK || echo FAIL
FAIL
```

However, if there is a shell script signalling an unclean exit, ssh always returns 0 (script simulated by string execution):

```
~$ ssh host sh -c 'exit 5' && echo OK || echo FAIL
OK
```

Running the very same script on the host in an interactive shell works just fine:

```
~$ sh -c 'exit 5' && echo OK || echo FAIL
FAIL
```

I am confused as to why this happens. How can I tell ssh to propagate bash's return code? I may not change the remote scripts.

I am using public key authentication, the private key is unlocked – there is no need for user interaction. All systems are Ubuntu 18.04. Application versions are:

- `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`
- `GNU bash, Version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Note: This question is different from these seemingly similar questions:

- [bash shell - ssh remote script capture output and exit code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390978/shell-script-ssh-command-exit-status
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726995/exit-code-from-ssh-command
- https://superuser.com/questions/652729/command-executed-via-ssh-does-not-return-proper-return-code

Comment: Are you certain that "sh" on the remote system is bash?

Comment: It seems like there was a similar problem earlier, where the shell doesn't fork because there's a simple command. Does the behavior change if you ask it to run `sh -c 'sleep 0.1; exit 5'`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, I am not certain. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` actually points to `/bin/dash`. Nevertheless the behaviour does not change if I use absolute paths (`/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` instead of `sh`). I hope there is no further auto-redirect going on.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, even `ssh host sh -c ':; exit 5'` yields the expected return code. This does not help me as in the real world script, there is a lot more going on. I want to examine what forks where and then improve the examples in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am able to duplicate this using the command you used, and I am able to resolve it by wrapping the remote command in quotes.  Here are my test cases:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo 'Unquoted Test:'
ssh evil sh -x -c exit 5 && echo OK || echo FAIL

echo 'Quoted Test 1:'
ssh evil sh -x -c 'exit 5' && echo OK || echo FAIL

echo 'Quoted Test 2:'
ssh evil 'sh -x -c "exit 5"' && echo OK || echo FAIL
```

Here are the results:

```
bash-[540]$ bash -x test.sh
+ echo 'Unquoted Test:'
Unquoted Test:
+ ssh evil sh -x -c exit 5
+ exit
+ echo OK
OK
+ echo 'Quoted Test 1:'
Quoted Test 1:
+ ssh evil sh -x -c 'exit 5'
+ exit
+ echo OK
OK
+ echo 'Quoted Test 2:'
Quoted Test 2:
+ ssh evil 'sh -x -c "exit 5"'
+ exit 5
+ echo FAIL
FAIL
```

In the first test and second tests, it seems the `5` is not being passed to `exit` as we would expect it to be. It just seems to be disappearing.  It's not going to `exit`, `sh` isn't complaining about `5: command not found`, and `ssh` isn't complaining about it.

In the third test, `exit 5` is quoted within the larger command to run on the remote host, same as in the second test.  This ensures that the `5` is passed to `exit`, and both are executed as the `-c` option to `sh`. The difference between the second and third tests is that the whole set of commands and arguments is sent to the remote host quoted as a single command argument to `ssh`.

Comment: It does not help me in actually solving the problem I encounter, but I am accepting this answer as it shortly explains what is going on.

Comment: Yeah.  I would really love to know there the `5` is going in the first two tests.  Especially the second where it's quoted to one level.  I guess the remote shell is eating those quotes before it gets to `sh`.  But I still don't get where the `5` is going.  If I run `sh -c echo 5`, the 5 is nowhere to be seen, either.  But `sh -c 'echo 5'` does what you expect and echoes `5`.

Answer (score 8):

As noted in [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489750/315749) you already have, the remote `sh` is not executing `exit 5`. Just `exit`:

```bash
$ ssh test sh -x -c 'exit 5'; echo $?
+ exit
0
```

What is happening here is explained, for instance, in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212298/315749):

*`ssh` executes a remote shell and passes a **string** to it, **not** a list of arguments.*

When we execute `ssh host sh -c 'exit 5'`:

1. The local shell removes the single quotes (*quote removal*);
2. The `ssh` client gets the arguments `host`, `sh`, `-c`, and `exit 5`. It concatenates them to a string and sends it to the remote host;
3. On the remote host, `ssh` invokes a shell and passes it the string `sh -c exit 5`;
4. The remote shell invokes `sh` and passes it the `-c` option, `exit` as the *command string*, and `5` as the *command name*.

Note that, if we add words after `exit 5`, they are just passed to `sh` as further arguments - no error related to them not being recognized by the shell:

```bash
$ ssh test sh -x -c 'exit 5' a b c; echo $?
+ exit
0
```

`strace` confirms that `5` is not part of the command string given to `sh`, here; it is an argument:

```bash
$ ssh test strace -e execve sh -c 'exit 5'; echo $?
execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "exit", "5"], 0x7ffc0d744c38 /* 14 vars */) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
0
```

In order to execute `sh -c 'command'` on a remote host as intended, we have to be sure to properly send it the quotes too:

```bash
$ ssh test "sh -x -c 'exit 5'"; echo $?
+ exit 5
5
```

To make it clear that quoting the whole remote command is not relevant to our current issue, we could just write:

```bash
$ ssh test sh -x -c "'exit 5'"; echo $?
+ exit 5
5
```

Escaping the inner quotes with backslashes, instead of quoting two times, would work as well.

---

A note about the command `ssh host sh -c ':; exit 5'` (from the comments to your question). What it does is:

```bash
$ ssh test sh -x -c ':; exit 5'; echo $?
+ :
5
```

That is, `exit 5` is executed by the outer shell, not by `sh`. Again, to let `sh` exit with the desired code:

```bash
$ ssh test sh -x -c "':; exit 5'"; echo $?
+ :
+ exit 5
5
```

Comment: This answer adds detail to the one already given. Unfortunately, I can only officially "accept" one answer. The behaviour still feels non-intuitive to me.

Comment: @Hermann No problem with the accept part, of course. Feel free to further point out what you feel _less intuitive_, answers can always be extended/improved.

Comment: The answer is fine. It is just the combination of ssh itself not needing quotes, but double quoting being a necessity as quotes are considered by both, local and remote shell.

Comment: A very informative use of `strace`.  Any idea what's actually happening to the `5`?  None of the shells seems to be doing anything with the `5`  without the double layer of quotes.

Comment: @TimKennedy The `5` (and what follows, if you add other words) are the zeroth and following parameters to `sh`. They are just unused here, except for the zeroth one that is used as the command name - but giving the command a name is probably not what we want. You could actually use them, and you can see them, for example, changing `exit` in `ssh test sh -x -c exit 5` into `\'echo \"\$0\" \"\$@\" \'`, as in `ssh test sh -x -c \'echo \"\$0\" \"\$@\" \' 5 a b c`. The whole point is that, without proper quoting, the _command string_ wanted by `sh -c` ends up being just the first word that follows.

Comment: i guess I'm not used to seeing arguments just disappear unused.  your explanation clears it up, though.

Comment: @TimKennedy, in the same way, just running `sh -c "echo foo" a b c` would ignore the extra arguments. The script (given as an argument to `-c`) just doesn't use them.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good at answering the question in lieu of the examples given. My real-world application is more complicated and involves a series of scripts and sub-processes. Here is a boiled-down example script I want to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash
sub-process-that-fails
# store and echo returncode for debug purposes
rc=$?
echo $rc
exit $rc
```

Trying to make sure that the remotely executed shell was actually bash and not dash (as pointed out by @JeffSchaller), I tried calling the script like this:

```
~$ ssh -t -t host /bin/bash -x /srv/scripts/run.sh ; echo $?
```

Which led to this weird output:

```
+ sub-process-that-fails
+ rc=5
+ echo 5
5
+ exit 5
0
```

After hours of poking around, I noticed there was a `trap 'kill 0' EXIT` set in the `.bashrc`. This is done to kill all sub-processes in case bash is killed. bash's trace does not seem to display this trap's execution. I moved the trap into the wrapper script. Now I can see what actually is executed:

```
+ trap 'kill 0' EXIT
+ sub-process-that-fails
+ rc=5
5
+ echo 5
+ exit 5
+ kill 0
0
```

The remote shell exits with the last command's exit code. It's `kill 0` and it exits with 0.

Comment: Also, if you just remove the `trap`, it works as expected, right? Similarly to `ssh $somehost /bin/false` setting the (client-side) exit status to `1`?

Comment: Yes. But the `trap` is there for a reason. Working around that is not the scope of this question, though.